# What's a good library for parsing mathematical expressions in java using user defined function which supports string as function parameter?

Tags: java, parsing, math

What's a good library for parsing mathematical expressions in java with user defined function which supports string as function parameter?

Any new updated library or we need to re-write this kind of library.

Eg.
"10+ userDefineFunction('parameterName')*70".

Comment: the best way is starting to write some code :D

Comment: You could write a parser for your expected input language. Or use a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
([A-z][A-z]+)\('([^']+)'
```

group 1 matches the method name, group 2 matches the string parameter, test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/2cHugo/1).

Of course this has some potential for improvements:

- method name is letters only
- no (escaped) `'` can appear inside the parameter string

but it works for the current example.

EDIT:

in java, using the regex looks like this:

```
String mathExp = "10+ sumRun('playerName')*70;";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([A-z][A-z]+)\\('([^']+)'").matcher(mathExp);
matcher.find();
String methodName = matcher.group(1);
String parameter = matcher.group(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start is to determine the *syntax* for identifying what a method call would look like.  Once the syntax has been identified, you'll need to create a *lexical analyzer*.  Do searches on the key terms here.  They will give you a good start into other threads for other approaches.  Another good key term would be *regular expression* or *regex*.